# SwiftUI - Custom map pin's onTapGesture action is selecting a wrong pin view when there are group of pins in the save position(Zindex bug)

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

My map code is actually really simple:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  MapTest
//
//  Created by Asi Givati on 24/04/2022.
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Combine

class ItemsManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = ItemsManager()
    var items:[Item] = [.init(title:"Pin1"), .init(title:"Pin2"), .init(title:"Pin3"), .init(title:"Pin4"), .init(title:"Pin5"), .init(title:"Pin6"), .init(title:"Pin7")]
    @Published var regionForMap = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.0525500, longitude: 34.80285150000003),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
}

class Item:ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {
    var title:String
    private let latitudeVal:Double
    private let longitudeVal:Double
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D { .init(latitude: latitudeVal, longitude: longitudeVal) }
    var id = UUID()
    init(title:String) {
        self.title = title
        self.latitudeVal = Double.random(in: 32.0525500...32.0847500)
        self.longitudeVal = Double.random(in: 34.80285150000003...34.814851700010030)
    }
}

struct MyMapScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject private var manager = ItemsManager.shared
    @State private var items = [Item]()
    @State private var selectedItemId:UUID?
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $manager.regionForMap, interactionModes:.all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.none), annotationItems:ItemsManager.shared.items) { item in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate, anchorPoint: .zero) {
                    CustomMapPin(item: item, isSelected:selectedItemId == item.id)
                        .border(.red)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItemId = item.id
                            // do something with 'item'
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct CustomMapPin:View {
    var item:Item
    var isSelected:Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title)
            .frame(width: 250, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .background(isSelected ? Color.green : Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyMapScreen()
    }
}
```

i need to do some action on the onTapGesture action, but the selected `item` is wrong when there are other pins below it.
it's like the tap action is going through the pin and click on the one that blow it.

when the view looks like that it's all good:

[image]

but when zooming in the issue occurs (click on the green pin - is execute the onTapGesture action of the bottom pin):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It sounds like you have too much tappable area somewhere in your `CustomMapPin()`.

Comment: @loremipsum i added more code, thanks :)

Comment: Still not something that can be reproduced. It is likely the rotation and all your hardcoded values. Like the -2. The tappable area is larger than you are "picturing". Try Simulator>Debug>Color Blended layers, you might get a better visual of what is going on.

Comment: @loremipsum A. thanks!, the Color Blended is really nice thing. but it didn't helped me to understand what is the problem. 
B. what hardcoded values? the only thing that is missing here is the Item object.

Comment: Copy and paste that code into an empty project and get it to work. Help us help you troubleshoot. Create mock locations, reproduce your issue with the least amount of code possible in a clean project, something we can copy and paste and see exactly what you are talking about. Look at the links I posted above.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks man, please try now :)

Comment: add `.border(.red)` to your `CustomMapPin` and you will see the problem. Adjust the size of your `Text` and `Triangle` so they do not overlap other CustomMapPin.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine it doesn't work =\ the red border looks ok but still.. when i click on the selected view, he select the bottom view in the map. i updated my code so you can copy and paste it and see if you can.

Comment: @loremipsum can you please check my friend?

Comment: Tested your new code and all 
works well for me, on macos 12.3, using xcode 13.3, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
 
The idea with the `.border(.red)` (with the original code) was to show you that the `CustomMapPin` areas overlap. 
If you zoon in, you can easily tap on any `CustomMapPin` to select it individually. If overlap selection is a real problem for your app, you may want to look at some decluttering algorithm.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks! yeah this is a project for my company, and this overlap selection is important to this feature. what do you mean by "decluttering algorithm" ?. and did see the issue with the overlapping thing?

Comment: I would report as a bug. It seems like the zindex/hittesting is reversed. It could have something to do with the map

Comment: there are many `decluttering` algorithms. Here is the MapKit way that may be of use to your app: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks for your time, i will take a look :)